# How are the values getting altered using the MIN/MAX function with Case statement to remove Nulls?

Tags: sql, join, case, isnull

Here i would like to understand what exactly does this SQL Query do. It gives me an output like the one i have attached below.

```
case when admit_disch is null then
   MAX(admit_disch) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY source.cono,source.resno ORDER BY source.date ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
else 
   admit_disch 
end as admit_disch
```

```
cono    resno   date    enddate unit    room    bed admit_disch in_out
02  322359  2015-03-16 00:00:00.000 2019-09-03 06:59:12.363 W   709 P   D   O
02  322359  2015-03-08 00:00:00.000 2015-03-15 00:00:00.000 W   709 P   R   I
02  322359  2015-02-20 00:00:00.000 2015-03-07 00:00:00.000 W   709 P   R   I
02  322359  2015-02-06 00:00:00.000 2015-02-19 00:00:00.000 W   709 P   R   I
```

When i do not use any any case function and directly call onto that particular column, it gives me output like this:

```
Output:
cono    resno   date    enddate unit    room    bed admit_disch in_out
02  322359  2015-03-16 00:00:00.000 2019-09-03 06:34:12.417 W   709 P   D   O
02  322359  2015-03-08 00:00:00.000 2015-03-15 00:00:00.000 W   709 P   R   NULL
02  322359  2015-02-20 00:00:00.000 2015-03-07 00:00:00.000 W   709 P   R   NULL
02  322359  2015-02-06 00:00:00.000 2015-02-19 00:00:00.000 W   709 P   R   I
```

Please explain as to how exactly is it working, as i am looking forward to implement the same for my dataset, to remove the nulls and replace them with the previous value whenever there is a null.

Comment: " i am looking forward to implement the same for my dataset, to remove the nulls and replace them with the previous value whenever there is a null" - if that's your requirement, why not ask a question *about that*? Because that's *not* what the query you're showing us does.

Comment: Can you please explain, what exactly does this query do?

Answer (score 0):

```
case when admit_disch is null then
   MAX(admit_disch) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY source.cono,source.resno ORDER BY source.date ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
else 
   admit_disch 
end as admit_disch
```

In english:

For any particular row R, if `admit_disch` is null then:

- find all rows that have the same `source.cono` and `source.resno` value that R has
- order those rows by `source.date`; this operation will place the R row somewhere in that ordering
- look backwards only, finding the maximum `admit_disch` in all those rows with a date that came before before R's `source.date`
- use that maximum value as the value of `admit_disch` for R

and if `admit_disch` is not null, then use the current value of `admit_disch`

---

Damien_the_unbeliever says this query does not "remove the nulls and replace them with the previous value whenever there is a null" because he (and I) have inferred that you're seeking the "most recent non null value", and this query is seeking the "highest non null value in all the previous"

These are slightly different things:

```
admit_disch  date
-----------  ----
1            2000-01-01
5            2000-01-02
3            2000-01-03
NULL         2000-01-04
```

This query will replace the NULL by 5, the max previous value. It will not replace the NULL with 3, the most recent non null value

---

Replacing with the most recent non null value might look something more like this:

```
CASE WHEN admit_disch IS NULL THEN
  SUBSTRING(
    MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR, source.date, 127) + admit_disch)
    OVER(PARTITION BY source.cono, source.resno ORDER BY source.date ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
  25, 1)
ELSE ...
```

That is to say, we convert the date to a string and add the `admit_disch` to it. When `admit_disch` is null this will null the entire thing. When it's a value, it tacks the `admit_disch` value onto the end of the string. Importantly, the date values are increasing so MAX will find the correct most recent one in all the unbounded rows. Th SUBSTRING will then extract the `admit_disch` again discarding the date.

```
admit_disch  date                     date+admit_disch
-----------  ----                     ----------------
I            2000-01-01T00:00:00.000  2000-01-01T00:00:00.000I
O            2000-01-02T00:00:00.000  2000-01-02T00:00:00.000O
I            2000-01-03T00:00:00.000  2000-01-03T00:00:00.000I <--alphabetically this is the max one
NULL         2000-01-04T00:00:00.000  NULL
```

You need an incrementing UNIQUE column or set of columns for this to work. Also if you have multiple dates that are the same, this may not work; pick another incrementing column/set

Comment: Is there any way i can remove these nulls, and use the previous value. To explain, as you can see in the second output attached, on the date 6/2/15 the value for in_out is 'I' and for date 16/03/15 the value is 'O'. These values are getting picked from the main table, i want the values to be modelled in such a manner that for all the date ranges between 6/2/15 and 16/03/15 the value for in_out should be 'I'

Comment: Read this: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/examining-scalar-function-performance-sql-server

Comment: I made an edit of how I think it would work (untested)

Answer (score 0):

```
case when admit_disch is null then
   MAX(admit_disch) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY source.cono,source.resno ORDER BY source.date ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
else 
   admit_disch 
end as admit_disch
```

If `admit_disch` is any non-null value, this just selects that value. Nothing complicated.

If `admit_disch` is null, then, considering other rows which share the same `cono` and `resno` values as the current row (the `PARTITION BY`) and which occurred previously to the current row, based on `date` (the `ORDER BY` and `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`), select the `MAX` value from the `admit_disch` column. Since all non-null values trump null values in `MAX`, unless all previous `admit_disch` values are `NULL`, this will produce a non-null value.

Note that it's selecting the `MAX`. This is in no way guaranteed (so far as SQL Server is concerned) to be the *latest* non-null value that precedes the current row. Of course, it may be true with *your* data that this will be the latest non-null value, but we can't say that just from this query.

Note also that if there's any possibility that multiple rows within a partition share the same `date` value you've got no guarantee on which, if any, of those rows might be included when computing the `MAX`. If that is a possibility, you should add more columns/expressions into the `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee a unique ordering.